# How to Split the AWS OpsWork output string in Chef .erb file.?

Tags: ruby, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

here is what i'm trying to achieve:

I have a chef erb file with following statement:

```
<% node[:opsworks][:layers][:mylayer][:instances].each do |private_ip| %>
- "<%= private_ip %>"
<% end %>
```

Which is producing the output:

```
"["mylayer2", {"public_dns_name"=>nil, 
"private_dns_name"=>"ip-10-0-1-157.us-west-1.compute.internal", 
"backends"=>2, "ip"=>nil, 
"private_ip"=>"10.0.1.157",     
"instance_type"=>"t2.micro", 
"status"=>"online", 
"id"=>"ba33dad5-c294-44ab-bdb5-d292e02e0658", 
"aws_instance_id"=>"i-a93bb169", 
"elastic_ip"=>nil, 
"created_at"=>"2015-08-26T11:58:03+00:00", 
"booted_at"=>"2015-08-26T11:58:45+00:00", 
"region"=>"us-west-1", "availability_zone"=>"us-west-1a",
"infrastructure_class"=>"ec2"}]"
```

and

```
"["mylayer1", {"public_dns_name"=>nil, 
"private_dns_name"=>"ip-10-0-1-253.us-west-1.compute.internal", 
"backends"=>2, "ip"=>nil, 
"private_ip"=>"10.0.1.253", 
"instance_type"=>"t2.micro", 
"status"=>"online", 
"id"=>"be6e9645-ef12-416b-9401-e7379c3f85e1", 
"aws_instance_id"=>"i-b90c9b79", 
"elastic_ip"=>nil, 
"created_at"=>"2015-08-28T08:39:42+00:00", 
"booted_at"=>"2015-08-28T08:41:05+00:00", 
"region"=>"us-west-1", 
"availability_zone"=>"us-west-1a", 
"infrastructure_class"=>"ec2"}]"
```

It's producing all the instance information but I would need the output like ( Only the Private IP's):

> - 10.0.1.157
> - 10.0.1.253

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: My Chef erb file content is: <% node[:opsworks][:layers][:sunjava][:instances].each do |private_ip| %>
- "<%= private_ip %>"
<% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on IRC, the instances data looks like it is probably a hash so you would want to grab both the key and value, and then grab the private_ip from the value:

```
<% node[:opsworks][:layers][:mylayer][:instances].each do |instance_name, instance_data| %>
- "<%= instance_data['private_ip'] %>"
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're confusing yourself by iterating through your instances, and calling each one `private_ip` as you do so.  Try this instead:

```
<% node[:opsworks][:layers][:mylayer][:instances].each do |instance| %>
- "<%= instance['private_ip'] %>"
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's not working: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer) on line #4:
 
2: storm.zookeeper.servers:
3: <% node[:opsworks][:layers][:sunjava][:instances].each do |instance| %>
4: - "<%= instance[:private_ip] %>"
5: <% end %>
6:

Comment: Still - same Error: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer) on line #4:
 
2: storm.zookeeper.servers:
3: <% node[:opsworks][:layers][:sunjava][:instances].each do |instance| %>
4: - "<%= instance['private_ip'] %>"
5: <% end %>
6: 
 
(erubis):4:in `[]'
(erubis):4:in `block (2 levels) in evaluate'
(erubis):3:in `each'
(erubis):3:in `block in evaluate'

Comment: can anyone please help me here.?

Comment: Here my instances has different names, irrespective of the instance names i need to get private IP's. Hope this help you in understanding my question. @IBam